# Unable to Read Firebase .json Within .jar File on AppEngine

Tags: java, firebase, google-app-engine, jar, kotlin

How do I adjust my **.jar** configuration to have the Firebase **.json** file read on AppEngine?

AppEngine cannot read the **.json** file to authenticate Firebase in my Java/Kotlin application. The .json file is read correctly in the **.jar** file when run independently. When the **.jar** is provided to AppEngine it cannot be read.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/kotlin/utils/auth/carpecoin-media-211617-firebase-adminsdk-5d3ii-574c2a8dd4.json (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at Initialization.initializeFirestore(Initialization.kt:16)
        at Initialization.main(Initialization.kt:10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround for AppEngine's bug I created an object containing the Firebase authentication data that I build from the FirebaseCredentialsHelper class. The returned object uses the String values generated from the Firebase console.

Then I converted my authentication object returned by the FirebaseCredentialsHelper class into json using the [Gson library](https://github.com/google/gson), and then into a byte input stream.

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseOptions.Builder()
.setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(Gson().toJson(FirebaseCredentialsHelper.get()).byteInputStream()))
.build())
```

Note: I kept the Firebase Authentication objects out of version control since they contain private information.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that @Marty! ;-)